# Is Star Wars: Clone Wars (Tartakovsky) still part of the official Star Wars canon?

Tags: star-wars, canon, clone-wars-2003

Per [this comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113306/how-did-grievous-abduct-palpatine/113316?noredirect=1#comment272384_113316) on a recent Star Wars question, is the 2003 Tartakovsky "**[Star Wars: Clone Wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Clone_Wars_(2003_TV_series))**" TV series still part of the official Star Wars (Disney) canon?

Comment: This one has a more specific and search-friendly title; besides, the linked one did not specifically addressed the point at that time. Richard [told in a comment](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/113306/how-did-grievous-abduct-palpatine#comment-272388) that he was going to update his answer to include this info too.

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - I'm working myself up to doing a major overhaul of my Star Wars Canonicity answer. Working my through mixed-canon and lower-canon items like this is stage #1

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Because, having encountered this question three times now, I felt a stronger explanation was required than just saying "It's not canon" and dumping a link.

Comment: @Richard you make an excellent point. I appreciate you working up a sort of star wars  FAQ

Comment: @AncientSwordRage - Self-flaggelation is apparently my style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, and in fact it stopped being part of the official canon universe ***prior*** to the [canon purge of April 2014](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/80098/20774) with the production of the new [Star Wars: The Clone Wars](http://www.starwars.com/tv-shows/star-wars-the-clone-wars) TV series which dealt with many of the same events.

Tartakovsky himself discussed this issue in [an interview with TheForce.net](http://www.theforce.net/latestnews/story/Tartakovsky_Talks_About_The_State_Of_His_SW_Clone_Wars_MicroSeries_148068.asp) in September 2012

> **Speaking of your version of "Clone Wars," does it bother you that there's another one and that the one you did seems to no longer be
>   canon?**
>
> *Yeah. I mean, you know, of course it bothers me. But, you know, it's George's characters. It's his world and he has to do what he has to
>   do. And the new ones are totally inspired by what we did: A lot of the
>   same character designs and stuff.*
>
> **Does that part bother you, too?**
>
> *No, again, it's not my characters, so he can do whatever he wants. And the story was also that I was going to do it. I was going to go to
>   Lucas and be their John Lasseter-type of person and do a feature and
>   supervise the "Star Wars" television show. And things kind of fell
>   apart, blah blah blah. But, yeah, I'm super proud of what we did. And
>   I felt like we did a justice to "Star Wars" and as a fan.*
>
> **I mean, people haven't forgotten them, even though we are supposed to.**
>
> *That's the one thing that is kind of weird that he just wants to wipe it off. Because we used to be in the encyclopedias, some of the
>   characters that we created. And now they're gone. And you can't get
>   the DVD and all of this other stuff. And it's like, whatever. What are
>   you going to do, right? It existed.*
>
> **But it feels like its been thrown on the scrapheap with the Holiday Special.**
>
> *I think George is brilliant. And I think he just wants to ... I don't know the reasoning, exactly. But from any sense that I can make out of
>   it, he just wants it to be clean. But there's so much fiction that's
>   out with "Star Wars," I don't think it would matter."*

Comment: To address any concerns raised that this was intended to "[farm rep](http://media1.giphy.com/media/6OWIl75ibpuFO/giphy.gif)", I've made this a community wiki answer. Upvote it, downvote, ignore it as you see fit.